# selecting a consolidated value based on another value in the same select query?

Tags: sql, netezza

Sorry for the poorly worded question, but i am consolidating customer records using the following query:

```
select
 customer_key
,FIRST_VALUE(name          IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_key ORDER BY last_updated_date desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS NAME
,FIRST_VALUE(county        IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_key ORDER BY last_updated_date desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS COUNTRY
,FIRST_VALUE(country_code  IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_key ORDER BY last_updated_date desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS COUNTRY_CODE
from            customers  cust
```

This selects the most recent record for a customer using the customer_key. but for country I need the country code to be on the same line as country, using the country field as the driver for this, but the country_code column is a NOT NULL field.

For example, this raw data:

```
customer  Country  Country_Code Date
Dave      NULL     0            30/08/2017
David     UK       1            29/08/2017
```

Needs to display as:

```
customer  Country  Country_Code
Dave      UK       1 
Dave      UK       1
```

But using the select query I'm currently using I get this:

```
customer  Country  Country_Code
Dave      UK       0 
Dave      UK       0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query should work .

```
  SELECT FIRST_VALUE(NAME IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
        PARTITION BY customer_key ORDER BY last_updated_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        ) AS NAME
    ,FIRST_VALUE(county IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
        PARTITION BY customer_key ORDER BY last_updated_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        ) AS COUNTRY
    ,FIRST_VALUE((
            CASE 
                WHEN county IS NULL
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE country_code
                END
            ) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
        PARTITION BY customer_key ORDER BY last_updated_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        ) AS COUNTRY_CODE
FROM customers cust;
```